NEXT router.back() --> pass data
I have an understanding issue of how to use next/navigation router and passing data while using router.back().
I have a page where user can create a booking on route /booking/new. In that form they need to select from a list of existing customers. If intended customer is not existing yet he can create a new customer by clicking on "new" which brings him to the route /customer/new. Now after submitting the customer form I'm sending him back by router.back(), because this page might be also opened from other places.
How is it possible now to pass the created customer ID to the last page (in this case /bookings/new) to prefill the selection component with that customer?
Does it make sense to pass the lastRoute to the /customer/new and call router.push(lastRoute, data) instead of router.back() or is there a more elegant way to do it?
Writing the customer into booking object in database before submitting is not possible, because some required fields won't be filled, yet.
